# Removing Isolated Values From Network Matrix with R

Tags: r, matrix, sparse-matrix

I have very a matrix like represented below:

`A=matrix(c(1,2,0,3,4,0,0,0,0),nrow=3,ncol=3,byrow=TRUE)`

In this matrix row and column names are same. Every row/column name corresponds an author which cites another.  3'th row and 3'th column are zero. How can I shrink matrix with removing isolated authors neither gets citation nor cites anyone?  In other words, the how can I remove intersecting n'th columns.

In [tm](ftp://cran.r-project.org/pub/R/web/packages/tm/vignettes/tm.pdf) (textual mining) library I can do it on document-term-matrixes with removeSparseTerms.

Answer (score 1):

Using `colSums`, `rowSums`, and `[` in base R, this can be accomplished with

```
A[rowSums(A) > 0, colSums(A) > 0]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    2
[2,]    3    4
```

This will drop any row or any column that is zero (no citing, no citations).

However, if the matrix is square, and the desire is to drop instances where both the column and the row are zero, you could use

```
keepem <- rowSums(A) > 0 | colSums(A) > 0
A[keepem, keepem]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to store as sparse matrix (and automatically store only non-zero items) then you can do something like the following:

```
library(Matrix)
A <- as(A, "sparseMatrix")
A 
# 3 x 3 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
# [1,] 1 2 .
# [2,] 3 4 .
# [3,] . . .
```